# Texbox que acepte solo numeros (enteros y flotantes)

Tags: javascript

como estan?

Necesito hacer que un texbox solo acepte numeros, ya sea enteros o flotantes. Esto es porque es un texbox donde se carga un importe monetario, y el mismo puede tener centavos.

El codigo que tengo deja cargar solo numeros, pero no le puedo agregar puntos ni comas:

```js
function solonumeros(evt) {
 
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (((charCode == 8) || (charCode == 46) 
            || (charCode >= 35 && charCode <= 40)
                || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
                || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105))) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtImporte_Cuenta" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" MaxLength="19"
                    Style="text-align: right" TabIndex="8" Width="120px" onkeydown="return solonumeros(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Como puedo hacer para que admita numeros flotantes? Muchas gracias

Comment: no puede ser con un input de tipo number: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp#:~:text=The%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22number,specifies%20the%20maximum%20value%20allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te adjunto una ayuda, el charcode para el punto es 110 y para la coma es 118

```js
function solonumeros(evt) {
 
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (   (charCode == 8) 
                || (charCode == 46) 
                || (charCode >= 35 && charCode <= 40)
                || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
                || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)
                || (charCode == 110)
                || (charCode == 188)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="return solonumeros(event)"></input>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, soluciono mi duda. Gracias Jose. Saludos